# Getting 'Invalid request method' error when trying to pass Scrapy data to Django using Python APIs

Tags: python, django, api, scrapy

I have a problem, I created a scrapy project and a django project with an application, I registered the application, set the urls, set the views, and also wrote the spider, but when I go to the localhost stand, I get an error

this is my piece of a spider with pandas, I only put the end here because the spider is ok , it saves the data to a json file on the disk, I want to send it to DJANGO

code is scrapy

```
 data_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
            data = {'data': data_dict}
            print(df)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/receive_data/',
                method='POST',
                body=json.dumps(data),
                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                callback=self.handle_response,
                cb_kwargs={'df': df}  
            )
            df.to_json('data.json', orient='records', lines=True)
    def handle_response(self, response, df):
        if response.status == 200:
            self.log('Data successfully sent.')
        else:
            self.log(f'Data sending failed. Response status: {response.status}')
            df.to_json('data.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

my views in Django

```
@csrf_exempt
def receive_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        toy = modul
        toy.xx = data.get('xxx')
        toy.xx = data.get('xxx')
        toy.xx= data.get('xx')
        toy.xx = data.get('xx')
        toy.xx = data.get('xx')
        
        if toy.xxx is not None and toy.xxx is not None and toy.xx is not None and toy.xxx is not None and toy.xx is not None:
            toy.save()
            response_data = {
                'message': 'Data received and saved successfully.',
            }
        else:
            response_data = {
                'error': 'Invalid data format or missing fields.',
            }
        
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
    else:
        response_data = {
            'error': 'Invalid request method',
        }
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

when I go to localhost, I get this error from view.py: {"error": "Invalid request method"}

I'm sorry xxx in the data but I have to

Comment: Try to set breakpoint on `if request.method == 'POST':` and run django in debug mode, so you can look at what stored in your `request`

Comment: This error happens when something is not filled in the python request form. If something is not complete the request variable will not be filled with the output. Try debugging it.